# Group By Ignoring NA

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am trying to get the following data to get the data in the following format into grouped by day and aggregating the shared variable with the mean function. Any assistance would be great!

```
dateA = c("5/8/2020 01:00:00","5/8/2020 02:00:00", "5/8/2020 03:00:00", "5/8/2020 04:00:00", NA, NA, NA, "5/12/2020 01:00:00", "5/12/2020 05:00:00", "5/12/2020 09:00:00", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
dateB = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "5/10/2020 01:00:00", "5/10/2020 05:00:00", "5/10/2020 09:00:00", NA, NA, NA, "5/15/2020 02:00:00", "5/15/2020 06:00:00", "5/15/2020 12:00:00", "5/15/2020 14:00:00", "5/15/2020 19:00:00")
varA = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
data = data.frame(dateA,dateB,varA)
```

Original Data format:

```
dateA               dateB               varA
5/8/2020 01:00:00   NA                    1  
5/8/2020 02:00:00   NA                    2 
5/8/2020 03:00:00   NA                    3
5/8/2020 04:00:00   NA                    4
NA                  5/10/2020 01:00:00    5
NA                  5/10/2020 05:00:00    6
NA                  5/10/2020 06:00:00    7
5/12/2020 01:00:00  NA                    8
5/12/2020 05:00:00  NA                    9 
5/12/2020 09:00:00  NA                    10
NA                  5/15/2020 02:00:00    11
NA                  5/15/2020 06:00:00    12
NA                  5/15/2020 12:00:00    13
NA                  5/15/2020 14:00:00    14
NA                  5/15/2020 19:00:00    15
```

Wanted Data Format:

```
dateA       dateB       meanA 
5/8/2020    NA          2.5
NA          5/10/2020   6
5/12/2020   NA          9
NA          5/15/2020   13
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do a grouping based on the `rleid` of non-NA elements in 'dateA', 'dateB', then convert the 'date' columns to `Datetime` class and change it to `Date` class (with `as.Date`), while getting the `mean` of 'varA')

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
data %>%
    group_by(grp = rleid(!is.na(dateA), !is.na(dateB))) %>% 
    summarise(across(starts_with('date'), ~as.Date(first(mdy_hms(.)))),
                meanA = mean(varA)) %>%
    select(-grp)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  dateA      dateB      meanA
#  <date>     <date>     <dbl>
#1 2020-05-08 NA           2.5
#2 NA         2020-05-10   6  
#3 2020-05-12 NA           9  
#4 NA         2020-05-15  13
```

---

Or using `base R` with `aggregate`

```
aggregate(varA ~ date, transform(data,
  date = sub(' .*', '', pmax(dateA, dateB, na.rm = TRUE))), FUN = mean)
```